# Is there a way to get the post title on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I want to get the post title on Blogger

e.g.:

```
MyApp for Android
```

so I can use it to insert a link with that title in it:

e.g.:

```
http://download.to/search/developer/?search=[title here]`.
```

Could I use JavaScript for this? Or it is possible to get it with Blogger?

Code Syntax is like:

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
```

Comment: thanks @user1846192 for the editing and sorry for my English :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the code inside the post loop, you can use something as:

```
<a expr:href='&quot;http://download.to/search/developer/?search=&quot; + data:post.title'>My link</a>
```

If you want to use in other part of the page, you can use something as:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://download.to/search/developer/?search='+document.title.replace('Some common part of your title','');">My link</a>
```

To do the same work.

Remember that in the second example you NEED to remove some common part of your title tag. Such as your blog name, for example. And that link **is not** processed by Google and other search engines.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I will try that.. and Sorry for my English :(

Comment: what if I want to Integrate that code for all my posts? how do I integrate the 1st example in the "loop"?  btw.. idk what that means >_<'

Comment: @rcotrina The post loop is all the content in your template inside the tags `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` and `</b:loop>` in your template, inside the widget "Blog1" (or something similar). To integrate that code in all your posts you need to search for `<data:post.body/>` and put the code after, or before, this tag.