# Get link <data:blog.pageName/> in url Blogger

Tags: xml, blogs, blogger

I would like to get the `mysite.com/<date: blog.pageName />`

Xith the name of the page and make a junction link by creating one, automatically do what is needed.

Exemple:

```
a href="https://blog-url-name-site.blogspot.com/(data:blog.pageName/)
```

(method not allow form permission intro xml save)

expected outcome

```
https://blog-url-name-site.blogspot.com/blogpagename
```

This link will be inserted inside the blogger xml edition

Comment: i find tanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258319/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-post-title-on-blogger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting code snippets for blogging on Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679189/formatting-code-snippets-for-blogging-on-blogger)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `expr:` prefix before href

```
<a expr:href='"https://blog-url-name-site.blogspot.com/" + data:blog.pageName'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make it with the below code.

```
<a expr:href='"https://api.whatsapp.com/send? 
phone=xxxxxxxxx&#x26;text="+data:post.url'></a>
```